# Remove unused libraries python pyproject.toml

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyproject.toml

I am using pyproject.toml to organize my python venv and later create environments with poetry from it.

However, over time more and more libraries have been added as a dependency but some are not used any more in the code.

What's the best/easiest way to find out which dependencies can be deleted without breaking anything?
I am thinking VSCode plugin, pip-package that analyzes python files in a directory, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can find obsolete dependencies by using [deptry](https://fpgmaas.github.io/deptry/), a command line utility that checks for unused dependencies within a project's dependencies. It also checks for some other issues with the listed dependencies.

You can add it to your project with

```
# For Poetry:
poetry add --group dev deptry
# For PDM:
pdm add -dG dev deptry
```

and then run

```
deptry .
```

Example output:

```
Scanning 2 files...

pyproject.toml: DEP002 'pandas' defined as a dependency but not used in the codebase
Found 1 dependency issue.
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `deptry`.

Comment: since you are the author of `deptry`, would you be willing to take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77441623/deptry-reports-dependencies-as-unused-although-i-need-them

Answer (score 0):

You could use AST to get all import statements by navigating all the paths,
then use tomlkit to read pyproject.toml file.