# deptry reports dependencies as unused, although I need them

Tags: python, python-poetry

In my python project, I use poetry version 1.7.0 and have a `pyproject.toml` containing

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
dogpile-cache = {extras = ["redis"], version = "^1.2.2"}
redis = "^4.5.5"
...

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
deptry = "^0.12.0"
....
```

The rest of the content should be irrelevant, but note there is no `[tool.poetry.extras]` section.

I install dependencies via `poetry install`, respectively `poetry install --withou dev` for production.

When I execute `deptry .`, it reports `redis` dependency as unused. There is no direct import of redis in my project code, but it is still required by `dogpile-cache`. If I remove the explicit dependency, my application stops working.

I did read up on poetry extras, but to my understanding they should not be used here, because they should describe optional extended functionality of my project and not extras of dependencies I want to use.

How to solve the situation?
Do I need to change some deptry config to have the tool stop reporting those repositories? Or do I need to adjust my pyproject.toml and the way I install dependencies with poetry?

Answer (score 0):

You can add configuration to your `pyproject.toml` to ignore the error for that specific package, see [here](https://fpgmaas.github.io/deptry/usage/#per-check-ignores).

In your case, add the following to your `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.deptry.per_rule_ignores]
DEP002 = ["redis"]
```

Comment: I understand this stops reporting redis as unused, but how can I be sure on other "unused" reports by deptry? At the moment this requires me to double check those reports one by one before actually removing them. I wonder if deptry should not automatically ignore unused depedencies if they appear in `extras` list of other used depedencies?

Comment: I think this actually seems to be an issue with `dogpile-cache` and not with `deptry`. When you install a package with an [extras](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-extras) option, that should install the base package plus the additional dependencies, and not leave it to the user to install those additional dependencies. In this case, it seems `dogpile-cache` is not doing so. I am not familiar with said package but I also don't see the option in their [source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Asqlalchemy%2Fdogpile.cache%20redis&type=code)?